# Django QuerySet delete() fires when?

Tags: django, django-queryset

i want to delete all records from a table in DB and refill each time my python script runs.

as far as i know when you make a django queryset, its just a queryset which is yet to be fired on DB, and this queryset is fired (executed on DB) only when i call functions like len() or function exits.

```
obj = table.objects.filter(name="abc")

len(obj)
```

My Question is

```
table.objects.all().delete()
```

does django fired query on DB as soon it encounters `.delete()` or wait for function to exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `autocommit` is `True` (default), `delete()` fires directly.

Note that there are some big changes with django 1.6 regarding [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: autocommit = true . will it fire for all queries or only for delete?

if it fires for all queries, i wont use autocommit,  are there any other options?

Comment: read the docs for in depth informations on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/